# ".NET Security's Levels" in C#, ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have got very big problem because I would like to get more information about ".NET Security's Levels" but in network I can`t find useful information(in professional way). This topic is very imortant for me can you give me some advices or send me some useful links.

Comment: What specifically do you want to know?  Lots to be found on MSDN...

Comment: ".Net Security levels" you know to security application in website (to make very safe website -hacker attack) in C# to make application very safe to (do not destroy application).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is information on ASP.NET Trust Levels. I would start at MSDN:

[ASP.NET Trust Levels and Policy Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyts434y.aspx)

Comment: I know this website. can you give more examples and some information about security levels in c# ?